# Handling regional currency variations in PHP - e.g. different uses of full stops versus commas

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm pretty certain this should be easier than I'm making it.
I have a client who's site provides loans to businesses and people.

The issue comes with validating the amounts people enter.
I need to strip out currency symbols, lose anything after the whole units (£ Sterling in most cases - so losing the pence) and convert the final number to a format that can be stored in a 3rd parties Database table as a Double.

The above was mostly working - except now we're getting users mixing thousand seperators and decimal seperators so need to work out if someone intends the full stop to be a thousand sep or a decimal sep.

Anyone got a clever solution? Is Regex the route?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Check if `.` is followed by 2 or 3 digits? 2 = pence; 3 = thousand pounds

Comment: that's a messy subject, the best thing is to force the imput being forced to use only decimal separator. If not you have to check if there are both separators and check which one is first to determine which one is thousands and decimal separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this (assuming your input is ok, no invalid inputs like "$6,00,00" or "777.7.98,$8938" or just "hi mom"):

1. find currency sign and strip it, it could be at the beginning or ending and can be more characters than one, like "USD", "CHF" and so on.
2. see if there is a decimal separator (the third char from right), if not add at the end "00" (like multiplying by 100)
3. remove all spaces, all commas, all dots, all `'` - I think nothing else can be a thousand/decimal separator, or maybe just leave only digits
4. divide result by 100

Comment: Thanks for this - sound advice and pointers. In the end I went with a function as below, but that does basically this...

Answer (score 0):

```
    function currencyToDouble($input) {
    if(preg_match("/^(.*)[^0-9]([0-9]{1,2})$/", $input, $matches)) {
        $val = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $matches[1]) . '.' . $matches[2] . "\n\n";
    } else {
        $val = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $input) . "\n\n";
    }

    return floatVal($val);


}
```

Was my final solution and seems to handle all my test cases nicely. Thoughts?